# How to find out the number of elements retrieved from a xml using javascript

Tags: javascript, xml, xml-parsing

I have a xml like this

```
<Summary>
    <Data>data1</Data>
    <Data>data2</Data>
    <Data>data3</Data>
    ...
</Summary>
```

Initially i used to do this when data was fixed

```
$(xml).find('Data').eq(0).text() // I got data1
$(xml).find('Data').eq(1).text() // I got data2
$(xml).find('Data').eq(2).text() // I got data3
```

What if i dont know how many Data elements are there. Is there any way to find out how many data elements i retrieved in my ajax request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if I fully understand what you want but the statement below would give you the number of Data elements:

```
var howMany = $(xml).find('Data').length;
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do something like this

```
<Summary>
    <Data>data1</Data>
    <Data>data2</Data>
    <Data>data3</Data>
    ...
</Summary>
```

/

```
/ initialized to some XML resembling your example
var dataXML = new XML("");  

// build XMLList
var dataList = dataXML['Data'];  

// alternative syntax
// var dataList = dataXML.Data;  

// how many data nodes are under a given data node?
var length = dataList.length();
```

Comment: Or, make use of `getElementsByTagName` method. Right?